# Doctrine2 query returns an object that not exists

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a **Doctrine2** project with three tables: **Product**, **Category** and **Rating**. Each Product has a one and only one Category. A Category may have a parent and many children.
Each Product has many Rating.

I run the following query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT p, AVG(r.value)*COUNT(r) as globalrating 
FROM AcmeProductBundle:Product p 
JOIN p.ratings r JOIN p.category cat JOIN cat.parent par
WHERE par = '.$categoryID.' OR cat = '.$categoryID.'
ORDER BY globalrating DESC, p.name ASC
```

where $categoryID is the id of the category where I'm searching for the products.
The point is that, notwithstanding there are no Products in the category, one result is reported. In particular, the object is of type Acme\ProductBundle\Product and has no values into the fields and **the id is 0**! Also the "globalrating" value is empty! I don't understand why?

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come back on the problem today and I found the problem, finally!

Reading the related [Doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results), I discovered that a `GROUP BY` clause where missing. So,  the right *DQL query* is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p, AVG(r.value)*COUNT(r) as globalrating 
FROM AcmeProductBundle:Product p 
JOIN p.ratings r JOIN p.category cat JOIN cat.parent par
WHERE par = '.$categoryID.' OR cat = '.$categoryID.'
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY globalrating DESC, p.name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT DISTINCT p, AVG(r.value)*COUNT(r) as globalrating 
                                 FROM AcmeProductBundle:Product p 
                                 JOIN p.ratings r JOIN p.category cat JOIN cat.parent par
                                 WHERE par = :category OR cat = :category
                                 ORDER BY globalrating DESC, p.name ASC');

$query->setParameter('category', $categoryID);
$returned = $query->getResult();
```